# VBA shell function cannot run the .bat job

Tags: vba, batch-file

My shell function didn't start the .bat job. Can anyone help?

```
Public Sub TESTRUN()
Dim Command As String
Dim pathcrnt As String
Dim RetVal

pathcrnt = ActiveWorkbook.path
Command = "RunMGALFA -ain:" & Range("AinFile") & " -val:" & Range("ValDate") & " -run:" & Range("RunNumber")

Open pathcrnt & "\test.bat" For Output As #1
Print #1, Command
Close #1
Shell pathcrnt & "\test.bat", vbMaximizedFocus

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script will not work unless `RunMGALFA` is either in the same directory as `pathcrnt` or in a location registered in your system `%PATH%` variable.

I would recommend supplying the full path to `RunMGALFA` in your generated script:

```
Command = "C:\Path\To\RunMGALFA -ain:" & Range("AinFile") & " -val:" & Range("ValDate") & " -run:" & Range("RunNumber")
```